# Quadratic variation of true martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

We know that for a continuous local martingale $M$ the quadratic variation $\left<M \right>$ is such that $M^2- \left< M \right>$ is a continuous local martingale. 
Is it true that if $M$ is a true martingale then $M^2- \left< M \right>$ is a true martingale?

Comment: Yes, if you assume that the martingale $M$ is square integrable. See e.g. Theorem 4.13 in Le Gall's Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus.

Comment: Interesting I would take a look to this martingale ( exemple 3 here https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/martingales-with-non-integrable-maximum/) to see if there is something that is exploitable in it for a counterxample.

Comment: To find a counterexample we would need, if $M_t$ follows the sde $dM_t = \eta_t dB_t$, ( for some process $\eta$ that assure that $M$ is a martingale), to show that $M^2_t -<M>_t=2\int_0^t\eta_s. M_s.dB_s$ is a strict local martingale (by Itô), so we need to find an example of $\eta$ that would break the condition $E[(\int_0^t(2\eta_s. M_s)^2ds)^{1/2}]<\infty$ which is a necessary and sufficient condition for $M^2 - <M>$ to be a true martingale unless mistaken.